# how to register an IRC user on freenode?

Tags: empathy, irc

I was following this link here http://freenode.net/faq.shtml#nicksetup but I can't understand a thing!! Where do I input these commands? in a terminal maybe? ...But I want to use empathy as my messenger. Is there something I don't understand?

It's clear that I'm a real beginner so plz give me a step-by-step explanation and instructions. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put these commands in the chat section, where you chat. Empathy doesn't support nickname registration

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Register-a-User-Name-on-Freenode).

Comment: Found out that empathy doesn't support nickname registration. That means that I can't register myself to chat through it. -that's as far as I understand- looks like I'll use Xchat after all, thanks anyways. Your link should help me when I'm done installing it. :) ...I think it's a good idea to edit the answer to include this comment

Comment: @MinaMichael I edited the answer, sorry I don't use that client, if you don't like xchat, you could use pidgin, I don't know if they support registration, never used it as irc client, there's also http://www.irssi.org/ if you like terminal clients